# Best datagrid library for Angular

Tags: angular

I'm trying to figure out what is the most efficient library of datagrid using Angular.

So far I tried a few, such as **agGrid**, **ngx-datatble** and **material**- all free source.
Some of them are really good at solving a few issues such as server side sorting/filtering/pagination (ngx-datatable) other (ag-grid) offer a range of FE elements. Tho, all in all, it's difficult to choose between them as none of them is perfect and covers up all the development needs

Which datagrid library would you recommend the most for Angular?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please note that this site doesn't feature requests for product comparisions: SR is about suggesting specific software for specific needs you define. For details, see: [Is tool x versus tool y a fair question?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/69/185) So please **[edit]** your post, list your requirements and ask for software meeting those, see [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link provides a comparing review on the existing datagrid libraries.

https://jsgrids.statico.io/

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [Syncfusion Angular Grid](https://www.syncfusion.com/angular-components/angular-grid/?utm_source=backlinks&utm_medium=listing&utm_campaign=angular_grid_stackexchange_backlinks), Its best and high performance speeds up the rendering large amounts of data.
Our [Angular Grid getting started documentation](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/grid/getting-started/?utm_source=backlinks&utm_medium=listing&utm_campaign=angular_grid_stackexchange_backlinks) is a good place to start. You can also explore our [Angular Grid example](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/demos/#/bootstrap5/grid/over-view/?utm_source=backlinks&utm_medium=listing&utm_campaign=angular_grid_stackexchange_backlinks) to understand how to present and manipulate data.

You can try our 30-day free trial to check out our Angular Grid and other Angular components. And all the Angular components are available at free of cost. If you are eligible, you can claim [free community license](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense/?utm_source=backlinks&utm_medium=listing&utm_campaign=angular_grid_stackexchange_backlinks).

Comment: Could you please prepend a disclaimer saying you are working for this company? And also say how well it handles sorting/filtering/pagination, any limitation? A screenshot would be great too. Thanks!